# How to create the below UI? Is there any library to create below image

Tags: reactjs, charts, view, lib

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZlFk.png)

How to create the below UI? Is there any library to  create below image.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you consider vector based graphics?

The below creates your is first shape in grey as illustrated in your image, then you can build on top of it to add the other shapes??

```html
<div>
  <svg width="400" height="510">
      <rect width="400" height="400" style="fill:rgb(128,128,128)" transform="skewY(-15)" />
      <text x="100" y="170" font-family="Verdana" font-size="45" fill="black">Wish</text>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Otherwise you can also consider Adobe Design programs like illustrator or photoshop to create that exact image and just bring it in as is. It will truly depend on your overall goal for your project.

Comment: Thanks,  i need  in funnel  format.  Is it possible  to divide the  section  into 3  sub  division.  Data  will not be hard coded  we will be  fetching  from  api. Is there  any react  library  to create  image  in this format